# Best way to run php scripts on website?

Tags: php, security

I wanted to check to see what would be the most appropriate way to run a php script on a website that does several updates and makes dynamic changes to the website.

Should these be run by putting the php files in the same FTP directory as the rest of the website and accessing
them as webpages?  If so, how could I control it so that only the web admins can access these links or php scripts?

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears off topic as it is not about code. You might be looking for [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com).

Comment: or [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/). There are just too many of them nowadays

Answer (score 1):

you might use a htaccess protection on a folder containing your admin scripts.

**.htaccess**

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files my-protected-file.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

**.htpasswd** (user:john, pw:john):

```
john:cH/Bl.u9Yl2x.
```

If you are protecting files, which live in an FTP folder, then move the htaccess/htpassword files one level up and adjust the paths OR set correct permissions to disallow reading (see comment).

```
/var/www/mysite/ftp (contains your admin scripts and has ftp access)
/var/www/mysite (has no ftp access, so add your protection here)
```

Comment: Make sure `.htpasswd` file cannot be viewed from outside. If you use it on shared hosting (e.g. have to put in `public_html`), ensure that proper chmods are in place.

Answer (score 0):

You gave us little detail, but I'll try my best to answer your question from as many standpoints as I can think of.

> Should these be run by putting the php files in the same FTP directory as the rest of the website and accessing them as webpages? If so, how could I control it so that only the web admins can access these links or php scripts?

If I were you, I'd add my own account management system in PHP, that does not use `.htpasswd`. Then I'd protect it with HTTPS so that passwords cannot be sniffed with packet analyzers. HTTPS is considered significantly stronger protection than using `.htpasswd` files.

That way, in order to execute the updates, I'd have to click a button or something similar after logging in. This allows you to easily extend your admin panel in future and makes it human-friendly.

Doing some work just by visiting a URL seems very fragile. It's very useful when it's supposed to be part of API, so that it's bot-friendly (see also: REST API), but in this case it *probably* shouldn't be exposed to everybody. If it's going to be used by bots, but should be available to only "good" bots, you might want to read about REST authentication methods (most of them rely on accounts of some form anyway).

Finally, if you want to run jobs in automatic fashion, research cron tasks. Then again, nothing prevents you from creating *both* admin panel and cron jobs that execute the same code.

If you don't want to put it in your public WWW folder, you're making it accessible to only those who have SSH access (not to confuse with FTP access). These people can execute that script using `php script.php` command. I guess it's not what you're looking for, since you never mentioned SSH access. Additionally, making your administrators connect to your server via SSH to do some tasks may or may not be an good idea, depending on the nature of your script and application. Other than through SSH, there are no ways to execute the script outside WWW folder, except for cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Put your php files in a non www directory.
For example, do not put PHP source files in a public_html directory so they can never be accessible by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the security implications of what you are designing?  I assume that you have some concerns since you mentioned authenticating admins.

[Survive the Deep End](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
[OWASP Home Page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Personally, I would not make the scripts you are describing accessible via the web interface.  Furthermore, I would not use FTP.  I have used cron jobs + wget/curl to call PHP scripts in the past, and the only benefit that I can see you getting from doing that would be a consistent language and consistent environment definition.  If there is nothing special in your environment that these admin scripts would need and they were to be run on a schedule, then you could just as easily invoke those scripts on the server from cron via the command line (don't expose the scripts via the web interface).

Cron works best if the maintenance scripts are run on a schedule, but never need to be run manually.  Do you ever use SSH?  Did you know that you can execute commands on the remote server in a single command executed on your local system?  It works quite well and would address your concerns about authenticating admins on the server- SSH is already a strong authentication framework when configured properly (not hard at all).

```
$ ssh username@server.domain.com "php /path/to/scripts/task1.php"
password:
```

The credentials (i.e. username/password requested by SSH) are those that you defined on the system itself (unless you are using Kerbose, ldap, or similar credential managment infrastructure).

You can also install update you scripts to the server without using FTP; yes, I would keep them away from "normal" webserver script files.  Perhaps you would find it easy to create a user account on the server, let's say you create the username maintenance, set-up key authentication and authorize admins to use the account by adding their public keys to the /home/maintenance/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  This way you can control (read limit the potential damage in case of accident, angry admin, crazy girlfriend, aliens... it doesn't matter because you only give the maintenance user permissions and access to the things required   to do it's job, can only write to the areas that are safe for those processes to write, and limit both read/execute permissions into areas that it doesn't need.  Jails or chroot are wonderful, but probably a bit too much to worry about at this point.

BTW, your FTP and web server should be running as users (not root) with limited access as well.  Hopefully you are already familiar with the concept I am trying to describe.

Imagine these accounts.

admin1
 Description: some webdude I decided to trust
 - id_rsa
 - id_rsa.pub

admin2
 Description: webdude's friend; I'm skeptical
 - id_rsa
 - id_rsa.pub

adminN
 Description: the Nth admin that I let manage the server
 - id_rsa
 - id_rsa.pub

youruser
 - id_rsa
 - id_rsa.pub

server
 User: httpd / www-data 
 Description: the user account under which the webserver runs

User: ftpd
 Description: the user account under which the FTP server runs

User: root
 Description: default account; ssh login disabled for root (learn how to use SUDO)

User: admin
 Description: The first user account created when you set up the server; this might be the account that you log in as remotely unless you created an account to match your username or have centralized credential management.  DO NOT GIVE YOUR ADMINS ACCESS TO THIS ACCOUNT.

User: maintenance
 Description: Newly created shared account that admins will allowed to use to execute the server maintaince / update scripts as they see fit.  Alternatively, you could create each admin their own account based on a template of limited privileges similar to this account.  That is a burden if there are a lot of admins or high turnover.  The main drawback to a shared account though is that it becomes a little more difficult to determine "who" is logging in because the account is shared- it's possible, but not as easy as just looking at the username; obviously.

Workflow.  When you add/authorize a new admin to your team you ask him/her to create an ssh key-pair (with a passphrase that is not empty) and send you the public key.  By default that file will be called "id_rsa.pub" and it is perfectly fine if anybody in the world sees the contents of that file- it is the "public" key of the key pair.  They should keep the counterpart (which is similarly named "id_rsa") private key in a directory that does not allow other users to read it (this is the default for the ~/.ssh directory) and if they suscpect that their private key has been compromised, then simply create a new pair and throw away the old one.

When you receive their public key, you will add it to the server's maintance account authorized_keys file like this; from your local system you are going to copy the "id_rsa" key they create and give/share with you up to the server.

```
# just to set up the example (not required once you understand)
$ ssh maintenance@server.domain.com "ls ~/.ssh/
id_rsa   id_rsa.pub   admin1_id_rsa.pub 
known_hosts     authorized_keys2    ssh_config

# That's an example of the files you should might see if you you, admin1, and the 
# maintenance account itself were already set up.  The public are just for record
# keeping and not actually required once their contents are added to the authorized_keys
# file.  If you don't keep the admin's public key files, then the following two commands
# could actually be done in a single step, but I've shown them as two here for clarity.
#
# Copy the new guy's public keyfile up to the server (admin2)
$ scp id_rsa.pub maintenance@server.example.com:~/.ssh/admin2_id_rsa.pub
$ ssh maintenance@server.example.com "cat ~/.ssh/admin2_id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

That's it.  You just added a new admin to the server.  If you want to restrict them from logging into the server too, you could configure the account to do that while still allowing them to execute the php scripts remotely via ssh.

Did that make sense?  Let me know if not and I'll try and clarify for you.